# products images not displayed in my wishlists in magento

Tags: magento

In my wishlist link there have some products but have no images.

```
That means i added products to my wishlist,but the products' images are not displaying in wishlists.
```

What is the problem?

How can i solve this?

when i click on add to wishlist i got some error so i copy the wishlist.xml and wishlist folder from base/defualt to my theme.
After that i cant  to see the images in wishlist when  i lastly added to my wishlist.
This is the error i got:
`

```
There has been an error processing your request

Invalid method Mage_Wishlist_Model_Item::isGrouped(Array
(
)
)

Trace:
#0 /hsphere/local/home/davidson/shop/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/price.phtml(52): Varien_Object->__call('isGrouped', Array)
#1 /hsphere/local/home/davidson/shop/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/price.phtml(52): Mage_Wishlist_Model_Item->isGrouped()
#2 /hsphere/local/home/davidson/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/hsphere/local/...')
#3 /hsphere/local/home/davidson/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/base/d...')
#4 /hsphere/local/home/davidson/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#5 /hsphere/local/home/davidson/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/Price.php(154): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#6 /hsphere/local/home/davidson/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Price->_toHtml()
#7 /hsphere/local/home/davidson/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Wishlist/Block/Abstract.php(383): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#8 /hsphere/local/home/davidson/shop/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/wishlist/view.phtml(61): Mage_Wishlist_Block_Abstract->getPriceHtml(Object(Mage_Wishlist_Model_Item))
#9 /hsphere/local/home/davidson/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/hsphere/local/...')
#10 /hsphere/local/home/davidson/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/base/d...')
#11 /hsphere/local/home/davidson/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#12 /hsphere/local/home/davidson/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#13 /hsphere/local/home/davidson/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(582): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#14 /hsphere/local/home/davidson/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(522): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('customer.wishli...', true)
#15 /hsphere/local/home/davidson/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Wrapper.php(52): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('', true, true)
#16 /hsphere/local/home/davidson/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Page_Block_Html_Wrapper->_toHtml()
#17 /hsphere/local/home/davidson/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#18 /hsphere/local/home/davidson/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#19 /hsphere/local/home/davidson/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(582): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#20 /hsphere/local/home/davidson/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(526): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
#21 /hsphere/local/home/davidson/shop/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/2columns-left.phtml(48): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
#22 /hsphere/local/home/davidson/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/hsphere/local/...')
#23 /hsphere/local/home/davidson/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/base/d...')
#24 /hsphere/local/home/davidson/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#25 /hsphere/local/home/davidson/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#26 /hsphere/local/home/davidson/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#27 /hsphere/local/home/davidson/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#28 /hsphere/local/home/davidson/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Wishlist/controllers/IndexController.php(150): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#29 /hsphere/local/home/davidson/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Wishlist_IndexController->indexAction()
#30 /hsphere/local/home/davidson/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#31 /hsphere/local/home/davidson/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#32 /hsphere/local/home/davidson/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#33 /hsphere/local/home/davidson/shop/app/Mage.php(687): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#34 /hsphere/local/home/davidson/davidsonbros.com/index.php(81): Mage::run('davidsonbros', 'website')
#35 {main}`
```

Answer (score 0):

> when i click on add to wishlist i got some error

What was the error?

Each column displayed in **My Wishlist** can be configured via wishlist.xml

```
<wishlist_index_index translate="label">
[...]
                <block type="wishlist/customer_wishlist_items" name="customer.wishlist.items" as="items" template="wishlist/item/list.phtml">
                <block type="wishlist/customer_wishlist_item_column_image" name="customer.wishlist.item.image" template="wishlist/item/column/image.phtml" />
[...]
```

Comment: check your Base Media URL (System -> Configuration -> Web -> Unsecure/Secure section). (also, clear cache)

Comment: @ Florinel, this is the unssecure and secure url:`{{unsecure_base_url}}media/` and `{{secure_base_url}}media/` .I also cleared the cache,but the images are not displayed .

Comment: @ Florinel, this is the image path of last added products to my wishlists :`http://www.mysite.com/media/catalog/product/cache/3/small_image/113x113/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/g/i/giant-navels.jpg`

Comment: @ Florinel , This is theimage path of products which are added earlier:`http://www.mysite.com/media/catalog/product/cache/3/small_image/113x113/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/u/n/untitled-6.jpg`